# copying an array of characters in c++ without using string functions

Tags: c++, g++

can anyone help me out with this code..
All i want to do is copy display the character arrays initialized in the main function
am pretty new to cpp and i can't figure a way out

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base1
{
public:
void setname(char *name);
void setpubl(char *publisher);
void setauth(char *author);
char getname();
char getpubl();
char getauth();
private:
char init_name[50], init_publ[50], init_auth[50];

};

void base1::setname(char *name)
{
int i=0;
while(init_name[i] != '\0')
{
init_name[i]=name[i];
i++;
}
}

void base1::setpubl(char *publisher)
{
int j=0;
while(init_publ[j] != '\0')
{
init_publ[j]=publisher[j];
j++;
}
}

void base1::setauth(char *author)
{
int k=0;
while(init_auth[k] != '\0')
{
init_auth[k]=author[k];
k++;
}

}

const char* base1::getname() const
{
return init_name;
}

const char* base1::getpubl() const
{
return init_publ;
}
const char* base1::getauth() const
{
return init_auth;
}
/*
base1::base1()
{
init_name[0]=0;
init_publ[0]=0;
init_auth[0]=0;
}*/

int main()
{
base1 hello;
char name[]="cpp";
char publisher[]="dreamworks";
char author[]="random";
hello.setname(name);
hello.setpubl(publisher);
hello.setauth(author);
cout<<hello.getname()<<endl;
cout<<hello.getpubl()<<endl;
cout<<hello.getauth()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

when i try to compile it it gives me loads of errors. can some one help me out.
i am using g++

errors:

> copychar.cpp:49:13: error: prototype for ‘const char* base1::getname() const’ does not match any in class ‘base1’
>
> copychar.cpp:10:6: error: candidate is: char base1::getname()
>
> copychar.cpp:54:13: error: prototype for ‘const char* base1::getpubl() const’ does not match any in class ‘base1’
>
> copychar.cpp:11:6: error: candidate is: char base1::getpubl()
>
> copychar.cpp:58:13: error: prototype for ‘const char* base1::getauth() const’ does not match any in class ‘base1’
>
> copychar.cpp:12:6: error: candidate is: char base1::getauth()

when i am using the following code, only the first character of each string is getting displayed

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base1
{
public:
void setname(char *name);
void setpubl(char *publisher);
void setauth(char *author);
char getname();
char getpubl();
char getauth();
private:
char init_name[50], init_publ[50], init_auth[50];

};

void base1::setname(char *name)
{
int i=0;
while(name[i] != '\0')
{
init_name[i]=name[i];
i++;
}
}

void base1::setpubl(char *publisher)
{
int j=0;
while(publisher[j] != '\0')
{
init_publ[j]=publisher[j];
j++;
}
}

void base1::setauth(char *author)
{
int k=0;
while(author[k] != '\0')
{
init_auth[k]=author[k];
k++;
}

}

char base1::getname()
{
return *init_name;
}

char base1::getpubl()
{
return *init_publ;
}
char base1::getauth()
{
return *init_auth;
}
/*
base1::base1()
{
init_name[0]=0;
init_publ[0]=0;
init_auth[0]=0;
}*/

int main()
{
base1 hello;
char name[]="cpp";
char publisher[]="dreamworks";
char author[]="random";
hello.setname(name);
hello.setpubl(publisher);
hello.setauth(author);
cout<<hello.getname()<<endl;
cout<<hello.getpubl()<<endl;
cout<<hello.getauth()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the compiler errors, and where?

Comment: And now that you have seen how hard this is, please use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Please do not edit the question on such a mass scale. It renders all the answers incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are wrong, not

```
void base1::setpubl(char *publisher)
{
    int j=0;
    while(init_publ[j] != '\0')
    {
        init_publ[j]=publisher[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

but

```
void base1::setpubl(char *publisher)
{
    int j=0;
    while(publisher[j] != '\0')
    {
        init_publ[j]=publisher[j];
        j++;
    }
    init_publ[j] = '\0'; // ensure destination string is null terminated
}
```

Your loop should check for the end of the `publisher` string that you pass into the function, not for the end of the `init_publ` string. That doesn't make much sense since you haven't given that string a value yet.

Same for the other loops.

Also look at this

```
char getname();
```

and this

```
const char* base1::getname() const
```

See the difference? First you say getname is `char`, then you say it's `const char*` and `const`. You have to be consistent. The second one is correct, replace

```
char getname();
```

with

```
const char* getname() const;
```

Same with getauth and getpubl.

Comment: @KiranVemuri Added another suggestion.

Comment: @KiranVemuri Glad you accepted my answer but the code I posted is not actually correct. PyotrNycz spotted an error which I had not. I've corrected my code to ensure that the strings you are copying to are null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The prototypes of your `getter` functions do not match.
You have declared the getters as this..

```
char getname();
```

And you implement it like this.

```
const char* base1::getauth() const
```

make their protypes same, like this.

```
const char* getauth() const ;
```

and implement it like this.

```
const char* base1::getauth() const
{
  //code here
}
```

And similarly for all `getter` functions.

Answer (score 1):

- correct your compile errors one by one

  - read every error carefully
  - check google/compiler documentation if do not understand it
  - still do not understand - then ask for this very error - what does it mean in your case
- unit test your code
- when your program will not pass unit tests (and it will not) debug your code and correct logic  errors one by one

Run these steps every time you must write something. This is the best way to improve your programming skills - good advice from others and good lecture are not enough.

I can give you some tips - but would that help for future, for not so obvious bugs?

Just one tip: char string must be ended by `'\0'`, are your strings contain this last character after copying?

Comment: If that's the only way to learn code then I must have been faking it all these years.

Comment: But that's a good tip, which no-one else seems to have caught.

Comment: Maybe before 'correct your compiler errors' you should explicitly list 'read your compile errors' since that seems to be the problem here.

Comment: thanks.
i did that when i found some garbage characters at the end of my strings :)

Answer (score 0):

- Your setXXX functions taking `char *` parameters should probably be taking `const char*` instead.

> ```
> void setname(const char *name);
> ```

- Your getXXX functions are declared as missing the `const` qualifiers, but definitions are `const`.
- Your getXXX functions are declared as returning a `char`, but definitions are returning `const char*`.

> ```
> const char* getname() const;
> ```

- Your setXXX functions are checking for null terminators in the destination rather than the source, causing them to not copy in any characters at all.
- Your setXXX functions should probably be using a for loop rather than a `while` loop
- You do no buffer overrun checks at all.

> ```
> void base1::setname(const char *name) 
> {
>   int i=0;
>   for( ; name[i]!='\0' && i<49; ++i)
>     init_name[i]=name[i];
>   init_name[i] = '\0';  
> }
> ```

- Your class has no constructor, so members might be initialized randomly

> ```
> base1::base1()
> :init_name(), init_publ(), init_auth()
> {}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the while thing on the argument :

```
void base1::setpubl(char *publisher)
{
     int j=0;
     while(publisher[j] != '\0')
     //...
```

It is the same for all your methods

Answer (score -1):

use the string functions, that's what they're there for (unless this is your homework in which case that's not what SO is here for)

However, your main problem is that when you copy the data to the class arrays, you stop when the destination array is a null - and in most C++ environments, declaring an array will not initialise it with nulls, most time you don't want the performance hit just to blank an array you will fill with real data.

So copy until the input is a null character instead, or the destination array is full.

Comment: got an assignment.. and hence